# searching for multiple strings in a column excel

Tags: excel

I've seen this question answered a few times but none of the solutions are working for me and I'd like to understand why.

I have the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(sheet1!$E$2:$E$228714,--(sheet1!$F$2:$F$228714="someword"), --(ISNUMBER(FIND({"word1","word2"},sheet1!$C$2:$C$228714))))
```

When in the third parameter of the function I only leave 1 word within the curly braces, it works great, but if I add "word2" in there, I get #VALUE! back.

I want to be able to FIND multiple words. Basically the third parameter would return 1 or 0 depending on whether it finds the specified words or not for every single cell in that row.

Comment: Perhaps try replacing the comma after "word1" with a semicolon instead. Does this fix the problem?

Comment: I tried this as well but it just returns a 2 which is not the correct answer. What that 2 means I'm not sure..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUMIFS(), with wildcards:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(Sheet1!E:E,Sheet1!F:F,"someword",Sheet1!C:C,{"*word1*","*word2*"}))
```

Comment: yup, always wait a few mins. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm having a bit of travel to translate your formula to a slightly different application. Would you be able to help me out with this one? `SUMPRODUCT(sheet1!H$2:H$228714,sheet1!$E$2:$E$228714, --(ISNUMBER(FIND({"word1","word2"},sheet1!$C$2:$C$228714))))`

Comment: i think the issue with SUMIFS there is that it expects a criteria with its second argument

Comment: I do not believe that SUMPRODUCT will do what you want. You can always SUM two SUMPRODUCTS, one that looks for the first and another that looks for the second.

Comment: What application are you using.  maybe another question stating the correct application will result in something you can use there.

Comment: Oh it actually does what I want in `SUMPRODUCT(sheet1!H$2:H$228714,sheet1!$E$2:$E$228714, --(ISNUMBER(FIND({"word1","word2"},sheet1!$C$2:$C$228714))))` but only if I use 1 word. Same problem as in my original question, hence why I'm hesitating making a new one

Comment: *What is the application you are using?*  If it works for one just do two SUMPRODUCT and SUM them together.

Comment: that works, although not the most elegant solution :(. Really long formula

Comment: Again, it would help if you stated what application you are trying to use.  There are other ways for example Google Sheets: `=sum(QUERY(Sheet1!C:F,"Select E  where F = 'someword' and C like'%word1%' or C like '%word2%'"))`